# Why are File Icons not visible in QListView?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, qlistview

I have a `QListView` in my application and want to display a list of files with their icons as shown in the QT Documentation.
QListView is in the `Icon mode`
I have the following code :-

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = result.begin() ; // got the results, now tie them to the StandardItemModel. 
        RespPara::stringList = new QStringList ; 
        RespPara::model = new QStringListModel ; 
        while(it!=result.end())
          {
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl ;
        RespPara::stringList->append((*it).c_str()) ; 
        it++ ; 
          }
        RespPara::model->setStringList(*(RespPara::stringList)) ; 
        RespPara::mainWindow->listView->setModel(RespPara::model) ;
```

Now, although the list of files is visible in the main application, the icons are not visible.
What am I doing wrong here? How can I correct this problem?

EDIT :- Here is the new code which is giving the same icon for all types of files :-

```
    while(!in.eof())
    {
      getline(in, buff) ; 
      QFileInfo fileInfo(buff.c_str()) ; 
      QFileIconProvider iconProvider  ; 
      QIcon icon = iconProvider.icon(fileInfo) ;
      QStandardItem* standardItem = new QStandardItem(icon, buff.c_str()) ; 
      myModel->appendRow(standardItem)  ;
    } 
  win.listView->setModel(myModel) ;
```

Here is the screen shot :-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you include the filename extension (ex: .txt) in `buff`?

Comment: yes , I have included it

Comment: What's the "same icon"? A screenshot maybe?

Comment: Ok posting it in a second.

Comment: @Tay2510 Posted the screen shot

Comment: It seems to be a Linux specific problem for Qt. Some Other guys had the same syndrome: [Link1](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17873-QFileIconProvider-and-OS-support-Not-using-all-icons-on-Linux) , [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761037/how-to-find-icon-file-through-suffix-of-file).  I'd suggest you take it as another issue.

Answer (score 3):

`QListView` is not that powerful to recognize the file icon, it's merely a listview. If you'd like to display icons in `QListView`, the conventional way is to instantiate a `QIcon` and set it to your model, for example:

```
QIcon icon(":/myIcons/theIcon.png");
model->setItem(0,0, new QStandardItem(icon, "Text next to the icon"));
```

There is no any icon set in your code, that's why you can't see them.

In your case, the `QIcon` should be provided by **file icon** and you have to seek help from [**`QFileIconProvider`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileiconprovider.html) class. The following code get the file icon from your system:

```
QFileInfo fileinfo("C:/cat/is/lovely/Test.txt"); // Provides the information of file type
QFileIconProvider iconprovider;
QIcon icon = iconprovider.icon(fileinfo); // return QIcon according to the file type
```

After that, you set the `QIcon` on your model.

[image]

Comment: Additionally it is worth implementing your own model class so that you only need to get the visible file icons (which you can cache)

Comment: Ok, but one more problem , the ListView is showing the same Icon for every file type, instead of showing different icons for different file  types

Comment: @ps06756 Can you show me the code? In my demo it did show different icons of different file types.

Comment: @Tay2510 Edited the question and posted the new code.